# Whats the best way to generate a XML output of a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

A bit on my requirements, at the moment i'm passing on a search string from a Cocoa app to a PHP script which queries the database, and then generates an XML output for Cocoa again.

The only bit I am having issues with now is generating the XML output from the db query.

At the moment, i'm trying to loop through the results and output them, however I am having issues, I can create the XML file but it doesn't get the results from the loop.

I can post my code if needed, but I'm sure somebody will have a more effective method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use PHP at all for the XML generation. [MySQL can do that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html). If the XML in a specific format you can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), but at that point it may be easier to use PHP instead.

Comment: Ideally I would, but I'm it's from a client app using search string, however I did see something about using XPath from a PHP script that looks promising.